# Q: Angular2: 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning Angular2, and following the "Tour of Heroes" example, when I setup a detail page for routing, I got this compile error from webpack:

```
ERROR in ./ts/router/route-hero-detail.component.ts
(25,23): error TS2339: Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'.
```

I'm using the webpack to manage the package thing,

below is the JS code:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }               from '@angular/common';

import { Hero }         from '../hero';
import { HeroService }  from '../hero.service';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.css' ]
})
export class RouteHeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero;
 
  constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      
    this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
      .subscribe((hero: Hero) => this.hero = hero);   
  } 

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

**package.json:**

```js
{
  "name": "environment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "I will show you how to set up angular2 development environment",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "environment"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot--host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "author": "Howard.Zuo",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.20",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./ts/index.ts"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    module: {
        exprContextCritical: false,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['ts-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.ts'
        ]
    }
};
```

**HeroService.ts:**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
 
    getHeroes() : Promise<Hero[]>{
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }

   getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
      return this.getHeroes()
               .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try importing import `'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';` after the other imports.

Comment: thank you, but it's not working... same error.

Comment: Can u share ur hero service?

Comment: import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
 
    getHeroes() : Promise<Hero[]>{
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }

   getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes()
               .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
  }

}

Comment: Sorry, I down't know how to format the code in comment..

Comment: Then put in your question! I am unable to edit your question, as there are pending edits to apporve.

Comment: no seriously, Smit is right. You miss the switchmap import and maybe even the map import itself (not sure) - so maybe check the right path of your libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<User>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873748/property-switchmap-does-not-exist-on-type-observableuser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue has been fixed, check below:

```js
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
        let id = +params['id'];
        this.heroService.getHero(id)
            .then(hero => this.hero = hero);
      } 
    });
```

Comment: You could also use `this.route.params.filter(params => params['id'] !== undefined).forEach((params: Params) => {`

Comment: Thanks, I'll put this in.

Comment: I'm stuck on the same tutorial in the Angular documentation 'routing' section. Did you find out why the switchMap() cannot be imported? Also, where did you come up with this solution?

Comment: If I do this, I get the error that says: "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Hero'".

Answer (score 74):

You need to import the `switchMap` operator:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';`

**update for rxjs >=5.5.0:**

for rxjs@5.5.0 or higher it's recommended to use the pipe operator instead of augmentation:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

\\...

this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => /*... */))
  .subscribe(/*... */);
\\...
```

(this avoids side effects and enable better bundle size optimization)

Comment: I am following the same Angular tutorial in the Angular documentation and receiving the same error. Why won't this import work?

Comment: can you elaborate on the piping ? Have any reference ?

Comment: @the_critic https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.0.0-alpha.3/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: @AmitPortnoy Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';   


this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap(user => {

        if (user) {

          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()

        } else {

          return of(null)

        }

      }));

    }
```

Comment: Answers containing only code are not considered complete.

Comment: Dear , you can import switchMap operator and try it works.

Answer (score 6):

The Angular 6 Update Which comes with rxjs 6.x.x you

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then simply wrap you switchMap with a pipe operator.

```
this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => {
  this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])
})).subscribe((hero: Hero) => this.hero = hero);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.pipe(
    switchMap(
      (params: Params) =>
       this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])))
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Angular 7 Update Which comes with rxjs> 6.x.x you

import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
Then simply wrap you switchMap with a pipe operator.

```
this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) =>
  this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])))
.subscribe((hero: Hero) => {this.hero = hero});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing in Visual Studio and also following the same bit of the Angular2 tutorial in the Angular documentation here: `https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html`, and I get the same errors showing up for `switchMap` even though I am using the import: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';`.

I realised that my app wasn't loading for me because the `.html` files were in the `src/app` folder - even though the Angular tutorial tells you to leave them in that directory. Nobody told me to do this - it was just by chance - that I moved both the `hero-detail.component.html` and `dashboard.component.html` to the `/src` folder and then the app began to show the correct results in the browser.